# Access to Cosmos db emulator on local machine from Linux docker

Tags: docker, asp.net, docker-for-windows

I little confused with Linux docker and cosmos db emulator. I have an emulator installed on my local machine. On my Windows 10 I have a Linux docker container with Web API ASP.NET core application. When I try to get access from container to cosmos db I get an exception -> HttpRequestException: Connection refused. In C# code I get needed options like AuthKey and Uri to database from environment variables. Looks like I have an issue with network between container and localhost but I can not understand how I can connect these. Below provided docker-compose.yml and docker-compose.override.yml files.

``````````````````
event.webapi:
    container_name: event.webapi
    image: '${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}eventwebapi'
    environment:
     **- AzureCollectionName=Events
     - AzureDatabaseName=EventsDatabase**
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Services/Event/Event.WebApi/Dockerfile

````````````````` docker-compose.override.yml
event.webapi:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44378
      **- AzureEndpointUri=https://127.0.0.1:8081
      -AzurePrimaryKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==**
    ports:
      - "53753:80"
      - "44378:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
``````````````````

Answer (score 0):

You need to add https://host.docker.internal:8081/ as the endpoint to cosmosdb emulator.